# Simple increment in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is a simple function, using jQuery, that would increment variables (A, B or C) depending on which button you're pressing. I'm not very good at explaining stuff, so let me just show you my code to give you the idea.

HTML:

```
A: <span id="a">0</span><br />
B: <span id="b">0</span><br />
C: <span id="c">0</span>
<div id="btn_holder">
  <button type="button" id="add_a">+1 A</button>
  <button type="button" id="add_b">+1 B</button>
  <button type="button" id="add_c">+1 C</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 var a = 0,
   b = 0,
   c = 0;

 function add(x, y) {
   x++;
   $('#' + y).html(x);
 }

 $('#btn_holder button').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   switch (id) {
     case 'add_a':
       add(a, 'a');
       break;
     case 'add_b':
       add(b, 'b');
       break;
     case 'add_c':
       add(c, 'c');
       break;
   }
 });
```

Here's the link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0drdu2bq/

Now, it sort of works, but it seems to only run the function once (it adds 1 and then the button does nothing). What am I missing here?

Comment: that's because javascript numbers are passed-by-value. So `function f(x) { x++ }; var a=1; f(a);` does not increase `a` by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript uses passes arguments by value, not by reference.
In your code, the function add is called with the value of variable A, which is 0. This value is stored in a new, temporary, variable X. X is the incremented by one and has it's value written to the screen.
When the function ends all you did was change the value of the temporary X, not of A, so that remains at 0.
The next time you call the function add, you pass in the value of A again, which is still 0 and the cycle repeats.

To fix the code, you have take the code out of the add function and put into the switch statement:

```
switch (id) {
    case 'add_a':
       $('#a').html(++a);
       break;
     case 'add_b':
       $('#b').html(++b);
       break;
     case 'add_c':
       $('#c').html(++c);
       break;
   }
```

See the full sample in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0drdu2bq/1/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for including the link to JSFiddle. That's pretty much the answer I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

Instead of

```
add(a, 'a');
```

put

```
$('#a').html(a++);
```

Otherwise, `a` won't be changed. Only the local variable `x` will be incremented and `a` will be `0` after `add(a, 'a');`.

**Method 2**

If you want to use your function, you could **return the incremented value**:

```
function add(x, y) {
   $('#' + y).html(x++);
   return x;
}
```

and then use it in the following way:

```
a = add(a, 'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use an object to hold the vales of a,b,c and use the letters as keys to the object

```js
     var values = {
        a : 0,
        b : 0,
        c : 0
     };
    
     function add(x) {
       values[x]++;
       $('#' + x).html(values[x]);
     }
    
     $('#btn_holder button').click(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       switch (id) {
         case 'add_a':
           add('a');
           break;
         case 'add_b':
           add('b');
           break;
         case 'add_c':
           add('c');
           break;
       }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
A: <span id="a">0</span><br />
B: <span id="b">0</span><br />
C: <span id="c">0</span>
<div id="btn_holder">
  <button type="button" id="add_a">+1 A</button>
  <button type="button" id="add_b">+1 B</button>
  <button type="button" id="add_c">+1 C</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of doing that this way, but I wasn't sure how.